# PidCrypt AES decrypt error - byteArray2String is not defined

Tags: javascript, encryption, arrays, aes, pidcrypt

I am trying use pidCrypt (javascript library https://sourceforge.net/projects/pidcrypt/) to decrypt crypted text by AES.

MAC mini, OS X Yosemite, v.10.10.1
Mozilla FF 35.0.1

I using this files:

```
 <SCRIPT src="javascripts/pidcrypt_util.js"></SCRIPT>
 <SCRIPT src="javascripts/pidcrypt.js"></SCRIPT>
 <SCRIPT src="javascripts/md5.js"></SCRIPT><!--needed for key and iv generation-->
 <SCRIPT src="javascripts/aes_core.js"></SCRIPT><!--needed block en-/decryption-->
 <SCRIPT src="javascripts/aes_cbc.js"></SCRIPT><!--needed for cbc mode-->
```

And making new instance:

```
 var aes = new pidCrypt.AES.CBC();
```

After this i get error:

ReferenceError: byteArray2String is not defined 
this.params.salt = byteArray2String(getRandomBytes(8)).convertToHex(); 
pidcrypt.js (line 93, col 5)

Same problem is if i launch test file packed with library (test_aes-cbc.html)

## Sloution:

I was fixed this that way:

Remove from pidcrypt.js:

```
line 93: this.params.salt = byteArray2String(getRandomBytes(8)).convertToHex();
```

Add to pidcrypt.js:

```
line 93: this.params.salt = pidCryptUtil.byteArray2String(getRandomBytes(8));
line 94: this.params.salt = pidCryptUtil.convertToHex(this.params.salt);
```

If anybody have additional info/notes to this edit plesae comment.

Comment: The original pidcrypt project has been abandoned. There is a fork here https://github.com/nikvdp/pidcrypt that has a little activity.